# How to verify mysql single process with multiple threads model?

Tags: mysql, process, threads

It is said that  MySQL handles connections, allocating one thread per connection to the server,and MySQL is a single process with multiple threads.

Now in my localhost .
There are two connections to mysql.

```
sudo ps -el |grep mysql
4 S     0   892     1  0  80   0 -  1084 -      ?        00:00:00 mysqld_safe
4 S   111  1338   892  0  80   0 - 172432 -     ?        00:00:21 mysqld
0 S  1000 14903 14892  0  80   0 - 27406 -      pts/1    00:00:00 mysql
0 S  1000 14937 14922  0  80   0 - 27375 -      pts/2    00:00:00 mysql
```

Let's search  892's ps tree.

```
 pstree  892 -p
mysqld_safe(892)───mysqld(1338)─┬─{mysqld}(1361)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1362)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1363)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1364)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1365)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1366)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1367)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1368)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1369)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1370)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1477)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1478)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1479)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1480)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1500)
                                ├─{mysqld}(1518)
                                ├─{mysqld}(2611)
                                └─{mysqld}(11598)
```

Are there 14903 and 14937  threads?Which process do they belong to? 
It means that MySQL server handles connections, allocating one thread per connection to the server.
Now for the process of 14903 on the mysql client side ,the mysql server allocate one thread for the connection,now which one in range 1361-1370 or range 1477-1499 or 1500 ,1518,2611,11598  handle the 14903's connection?

Comment: Re your edit: Why is that important. What problem do you try to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between `mysqld` and `mysql`. The latter is the *client* program you use to manage the server.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ps -ef | grep mysql` shows clearly that these processes are mysql clients

```
0 S  1000 14903 14892  0  80   0 - 27406 -      pts/1    00:00:00 mysql
0 S  1000 14937 14922  0  80   0 - 27375 -      pts/2    00:00:00 mysql
```

The server process ends with `d` letter.